# Monochromatic $4$-Cycle in Bipartite Complete Graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, contest-math, bipartite-graphs

> Given a complete bipartite graph on $n$, $n$ vertices (call this $K_{n,n}$), we colour all its
> edges using two colours, red and blue. What is the least value of $n$ such that for any colouring
> of the edges of this graph, there will exist at least one monochromatic $4$-cycle?

This is a question from a high school advanced math exam in india (STEMS 2022 - Tessellate CMI). I was trying this question but I've got nothing worth telling or extremely non-trivial. I have studied graph theory but I havent practiced a lot of it, especially no proof based questions, that's probably why I'm not able to do much progress. If someone can share a solution, It will be great.

Answer (score 2):

Let one part be $\{\,v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n\,\}$ and another part be $\{\,u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_n\,\}$.

Let's show that for $n = 5$ the graph always has a monochromatic $4$-cycle. Suppose the opposite. Among edges $v_1u1, v_1u_2, \ldots, v_1u_5$ at least $\lceil 5 / 2\rceil = 3$ have the same color. Without loss of generality edges $v_1u_1$, $v_1u_2$ and $v_1u_3$ are red. Since there is no monochromatic $4$-cycle, at least $2$ of edges $v_ku_1$, $v_ku_2$ and $v_ku_3$ are blue for all $k = 2, 3, 4, 5$. Again without loss of generality $v_2u_1$ and $v_2u_2$ are blue. Then $v_ku_3$ and exactly one of $v_ku_1$ and $v_ku_2$ are blue for $k = 3, 4, 5$. It means that for two of such $v_k$'s ($3 \le k \le 5$) blue edges go to $u_3$ and the same $u_i$ ($1 \le i \le 2$). Thus $K_{5, 5}$ always has a monochromatic $4$-cycle.

To show that $n = 5$ is minimum possible let's color $K_{4, 4}$ such that it will not have a monochromatic $4$-cycle: edges $v_1u_1$, $v_1u_2$, $v_2u_1$, $v_2u_3$, $v_3u_2$, $v_3u_4$, $v_4u_3$ and $v_4u_4$ are red, all other edges are blue. It is easy to see that each vertex has $2$ red and $2$ blue edges, and for each $v_i$ set of ends $u_j$ of red edges is unique. The same with blue edges.

Comment: In fact the edges of $K_{4,6}$ can be $2$-colored without a monochromatic $4$-cycle: let each of the vertices $v_1,\dots,v_6$ be joined by red edges to a different $2$-element subset of $\{u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4\}$. Of course this is not possible for $K_{3,7}$.

Comment: @user14111 you are right, but the question was about $K_{n, n}$

Answer (score 0):

$K_{4,4}$ is not big enough to ensure the existence of a monochromatic $4$-cycle.

[image]

$K_{5,5}$, however, is. In fact, let $U, V$ be the bipartition over its vertices. Notice every vertex has more edges of one color than the other, so, by the Pigeonhole Principle, there are as least three vertices $U$ having, say, more red than blue edges (i.e., at least three red edges). Since the red neighborhood (neighborhood through a red edge) of these vertices is within the five elements of $V$, again by the Pigeonhole Principle, two of the three vertices share two elements in their red neighborhood. This give us our $4$-cycle. $\square$

[image]